# Unable to deploy using wildfly-maven-plugin 2.0.1 in JBoss EAP 6.4 environment

Tags: jboss, maven-plugin, jboss6.x

Getting the below error while trying to deploy in JBoss EAP 6.4 environment using wildfly-maven-plugin 2.0.1. While changing the native port from default (9999) to any other port it's failing with the below error.
java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9993. The connection failed: Invalid response

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>${wild.hostname}</hostname>
        <port>${wild.port}</port>
        <username>${wild.username}</username>
        <password>${wild.password}</password>
        <name>${wild.name}</name>
        <timeout>60000</timeout>
        <server-groups>${wild.servergroups}</server-groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you overriding the port on the server and in the maven configuration?

Comment: Yeah.. changing the default native port from 9999 to 9993. It's working fine for 9999.

Comment: What does the maven configuration look like? From the error message it looks like the port is not being overridden.

Comment: Maven configuration needs to be overridden as well? Can you please share some sample.

Comment: wildfly:undeploy  and wildfly:deployis being used for undeploy and deploy. Reference:  https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

Comment: What does the configuration in your pom look like though. Does it have `<skip>false</skip>`?

Comment: <skip>false</skip> is not used.

The WIldfly Plugun Part is:
<plugin>
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.Final</version>
<configuration>
<hostname>${wild.hostname}</hostname>
<port>${wild.port}</port>
<username>${wild.username}</username>
<password>${wild.password}</password>
<name>${wild.name}</name>
<timeout>60000</timeout>
<server-groups>${wild.servergroups}</server-groups>
</configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: My apologies on that comment. I was mistaking this for a different post I was replying to. Given that configuration though as long as `wild.port` is set to 9993 and the domain server is running admin on 9993 then that should definitely work.

Comment: wild.port is set to 9993 and domain server is running on 9993. It's not working. But working properly on 9999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is some special code that automatically overrides the protocol when using port 9999. Since you've changed the port you're also going to need to override the protocol. From the command line you can use `-Dwildfly.protocol=remoting`.

For your configuration you'd just need to add `<protocol>remoting</protocol>`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>${wild.hostname}</hostname>
        <port>${wild.port}</port>
        <username>${wild.username}</username>
        <password>${wild.password}</password>
        <name>${wild.name}</name>
        <timeout>60000</timeout>
        <protocol>remoting</protocol>
        <server-groups>${wild.servergroups}</server-groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hey James.. Thanks :) 
After adding the remoting tag initial issue is resolved and got a new one.

javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05053: Callback handler failed for unknown reason [Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: The environment does not have a usable console. Cannot prompt for user name and password]

Any help on this please.

Comment: Do you have the `wild.username` and `wildf.password` defined? If empty it will attempt to use a console to prompt for a username and password.

Comment: wild.hostname, wild.port, wild.username and wild.password is defined. 
The connection failed: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
[ERROR] DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05053: Callback handler failed for unknown reason [Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: The environment does not have a usable console. Cannot prompt for user name and password]

Comment: When I tested it worked when those were defined. If they were empty I'd get prompted on my console to enter the text.

Answer (score 0):

I used it as profile under maven pom file - that will be execute on demand.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>deploy-ewfsa-api</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
                    <version>${wildfly.version></version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ewfsa-api-deploy</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                             <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                             <username>${wildfly.server.admin.user}</username>
                             <password>${wildfly.server.admin.passwd}</password>
                             <force>true</force>
                             <hostname>${wildfly.host.name}</hostname>
                             <port>${wildfly.port.number}</port>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<properties>
  <!-- assume below user configuration should be there with applicable permissions -->
  <wildfly.server.admin.user>admin</wildfly.server.admin.user>
  <wildfly.server.admin.passwd>admin@123</wildfly.server.admin.passwd>
  <wildfly.host.name>localhost</wildfly.host.name>
  <wildfly.port.number>9990</wildfly.port.number>
  <wildfly.version>4.0.0.Final</wildfly.version>
<properties>
```

To run this maven profile, I created an ant task. The ant task is as below -

```
<target name="Deploy(ewfsa-api)">
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
        <arg value="-cx"/>
        <arg value="mvn package -pl ${ewfsa-api} -am -Pdeploy-ewfsa-api"/>
    </exec>
</target>
<!-- project path -->
<property name="ewfsa-api">modules/delivery/ewfsa-api</property>
```

The same way we can do for undeploy and redeploy goals, those are provided by wildfly-maven-plugin.

The given code snippets (first part) must be under pom.xml while 2nd part in ant task build file.